# Nested WHILE loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am a beginner with Python and trying few programs. I have something like the following WHILE loop construct in Python (not exact).

```
IDLE 2.6.4      
>>> a=0
>>> b=0
>>> while a < 4:
      a=a+1
      while b < 4:
         b=b+1
         print a, b

  
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

I am expecting the outer loop to loop through 1,2,3 and 4. And I know I can do this with FOR loop like this

```
>>> for a in range(1,5):
       for b in range(1,5):
           print a,b

  
1 1
1 2
.. ..
.. .. // Other lines omitted for brevity
4 4
```

But, what is wrong with WHILE loop? I guess I am missing some thing obvious, but could not make out.

**Answer:**
The corrected WHILE loop..

```
>>> a=0
>>> while a < 4:
    a=a+1
    b=0
    while b<4:
        b=b+1
        print a,b

        
1 1
.. ..
.. .. // Other lines omitted for brevity
4 4
```

**P.S**: Searched out SO, found [few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421323/nested-while-loop-in-python) but none as close to this. Don't know whether this could classified as homework, the actual program was different, the problem is what puzzles me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not resetting `b` to 0 right inside your outer loop, so `b` stays at the value it had after the first leg of the outer loop -- 4 -- and the inner loop never executes again.

The `for` loops work fine because they *do* reset their loop control variables correctly; with the less-structured `while` loops, such resetting is in your hands, and you're not doing it.