# How to write a loop inside a loop with python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Just started to learn programming..
here my question, using Python how I can write a while loop inside another while loop??

```
while A > 10:
B +=10

    while x < 12:
       x +=1
       A =  bla bla some function depending on B
```

how is the correct syntax??

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. Did you try something and it didn't work? If that's the case you should show us what didn't work. Because unless you don't update A properly such that you get termination, this is fine. The syntax is certainly correct (obv except for the fact that "bla bla some function...." is not python)

Comment: @Cruncher: There's also the fact that `B+=10` needs to be indented.

Comment: @jwodder oops, yes. That. I was assuming that the first loop was correct given the question, so I didn't really validate that part xD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421323/nested-while-loop-in-python

Comment: what do u mean with "needs to be indented"??

Comment: Remember that blocks in python are determined by their level of indentation, not by curly braces or the word "end".  Since the line `B+=10` is inside the first `while` loop, it must be indented so that python knows it is in the loop.  See the answer from @Christian for a visual of what that means.

Answer (score 5):

This is a nested while inside another one. Remember to indent correctly.

```
while A > 10:
    B += 10
    while x < 12:
        x += 1
        A = bla bla some function depending on B
```

Comment: Edited so it matchs Official Python style.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to declare A before entering the while loop (e.g. by setting it to `True`.